# making ffmpeg recognise mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

What should I install on ubuntu 10.04 to allow my ffmpeg convert files to MP4 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing unstripped libraries:

```
sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-unstripped-51 libavdevice-unstripped-52 libavformat-unstripped-52 libavutil-unstripped-49 libpostproc-unstripped-51 libswscale-unstripped-0 ffmpeg
```

(Suggested [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6207546&postcount=3))